# jquery ui table sortable with pagination

Tags: jquery-ui, datatable, pagination, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable with table and it works fine.
When I use pagination (I save the new order of datatble items in the DB via ajax post) the table lose the order and the new order will appear only if I refresh the page (because I will get the entities from the DB)
How can I kepping the new order while using pagination ?

```
$("tbody").sortable({
        axis:'y',
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        group: 'no-drop',
        handle: '.drag',
        update: function (event, ui) {

            var videoSortedIDS = $(this).sortable("toArray");
            var ranks = [];
            for (r = pageInfo.start; r < pageInfo.end; r++) {
                ranks.push(r);
            }

            $.post(urlSort, {videoIDS: videoSortedIDS, videoRanks: ranks}, function (data) {
                if (data.responseCode === 200) {
                    console.log(data.sortedEntities);
                } else {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: the problem is : if I make a sort, then I move to another page of the table using pagination then I back to the sorted page, the table show the initial order

Comment: I found a solution !
Since the jquery Sortable don't affect the object instanciated with Datatable,
I update every row in the Datatable table with the new content of the html table using table.row(index).data(newRowContent).draw(false).
draw(false) to save the page state ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution ! Since the jquery Sortable don't affect the object instanciated with Datatable, I update every row in the Datatable table with the new content of the html table:

```
table.row(index).data(newRowContent).draw(false);
```

draw(false) to save the page state ;)